# Order rejected: Today's expiring option series on this symbol are Closing Only

Tags: options

Rejected    Buy to Open     1

Order rejected:     Today's expiring option series on this symbol are Closing Only.

TDA gives me this response when I try to buy 1 call option OTM The volume and open interest on the call is quite high(several thousand each and climbing).

Comment: Is this a GameStop or similar issue?  It's unusual for a broker to restrict trading for every day securities.

Comment: @BobBaerker Yes, I'm trying to buy an 800 call for a few bucks just for the hell of it.

Comment: Well, that explains it.  They're still trying to manage and control the GME issue.  Not exactly a good bet but hope spring eternal :->)

Comment: The odds of making much money on an $800 call that is $675 out-of-the-money are slim.  The delta of that call for next week is probably less than .05 which means it's a really long shot bet.  If you buy it, there will be no restrictions on closing orders.

Comment: @BobBaerker Yes, it is almost zero, but there is a non-zero finite chance and it's only a $2 bet. I'm still trying to figure out this whole GME thing, if it really is just a huge pump and dump or if one can actually make money going long. Seems like there is a much bigger picture going on that I'm missing due to my ignorance in the markets and such. I've learned a ton though and understand the market far better and how they are manipulated. (I know it is manipulated but I never spent the time to learn details since I have hobbies that actually make me happy)

Comment: Just trying to figure out if GME is really a multi level scam to take out retail apes who FOMO and YOLO or if it is actually finally caught the HF's and Gov in a gambit. All I know is something big will happen, I really hope it will be good for humanity. If I can make some money to make my life better then that is a bonus, but I definitely don't want to make elites lives better at the cost of mine.

Comment: Oh, and I was able to buy a put for next week so I have it. It cost me 1.65$ Hopefully I can make more sense of options by then. I understand the basics but have to work on getting comfortable with how they can be used to actually make money. Right now I just want to have some cheap calls and puts just in case something major happens before I figure more out.

Comment: As they say, "Good judgement comes from experience and experience comes from bad judgement.  Good luck but you're playing with fire.

Comment: @BobBaerker I've played with fire before... got burned, still alive ;) It seems that how one really gets burned is all the BS artificial rules in place for the brokerages to maximize profit and reduce risk. Supposedly it is to protect the little moron who isn't smart enough to play the game but we both know they don't care about the little guy. (yes, it is very easy to lose a ton of money but notice they never pop up a warning about selling for a huge loss. They don't give you a probabiblity of being able to recover if you wait. They auto exercise no matter what, will loan out your shares,etc)

Comment: Auto exercise is an Option Clearing Corp rule.  They broker is just the middleman on that one.  Cash account shares cannot be loaned out.  I believe there's a no loan exemption agreement that you can sign for a margin account.  Check with your broker on that one.  I get that you'd like it to be different but the bottom line is that brokers are in the business to make money.  There's no hand holding for zero commission brokers.  Back in the day, commissions were exhorbitant and there was more service, though it was quite costly.

Comment: @BobBaerker I don't mind that, what I mind is how they manipulate things to maximize profits. E.g., CC send me an email saying they have received my payment... but of course payment doesn't go through for 2 days giving them 2 days for something funky to happen. They literally say "Payment received"... yet they haven't received the actually payment(the money). IMO that is intentional to screw people. They could say "Payment has been requested, ETA 2 days for payment" but then that is not optimal to extract $$$ from retail.